# Setting Grid border in WP7

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to create grid with borders but with this code, only the first cell has border:

```
<Grid Margin="24,96,24,288" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.150*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.150*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.150*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.150*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.150*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.150*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.150*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.150*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.150*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.150*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.150*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.150*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1"/>
</Grid>
```

How do I create solid border for all the cells?

Answer (score 28):

Wrap the Grid **into** a [Border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx) :

```
<Border  BorderBrush="#FF0000" BorderThickness="5" Margin="24,96,24,288">
    <Grid>
       ....
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The way you did was adding a Border-element **into** the Grid-Control - so of course the first cell (if you don't set Grid.Row/Grid.Column both will default to 0) was drawn with one ;)

If you want to create a border for each cell then you have to wrap each content into a Border-element or you have to edit the template for the grid.
As another alternative you could try to style the Grid (here is a nice [article](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/2941-styling-wpf-datagrid.aspx))
Here is another question from this site concerning a similar thing: [Styling a WPF layout grid background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/565243/76051)

To make this a bit clearer the easiest (if not most refined) way to get a (even) border for each cell is to really set the boarder for each cell AND for the grid yourself (either in markup or code) - here is a simplified example:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF0000" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="24,96,24,288" >
    <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border BorderBrush="#FF0000" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF0000" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF0000" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF0000" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Well I actually tried this as well but it doesn't work either.

Comment: what the boarder around the grid? ... sure this didn't give you a border around your grid?

Comment: sorry I don't get your question, however this way it draws nothing. No borders around grid or cells.

Comment: might be the example was ill choosen (copied your markup for the color and thickness ;)) - I will change it a bit so you should see the effect because I guess you don't see a small white line in this case...

Comment: So basically you need to add million border definitions by hand to get this work, great... Thanks for the clarification! However, decided to go with canvas.

Comment: No you don't need to - you have several options. You could set all the borders with two simple for-loops in the code-behind. Or you could change the template of the grid. But this one is the simplest one and the template option can be found by a simple google search or a question here *after* you tried yourself. This is a FAQ site not a "do my job" site. And if you are talking about a million grid cells (so basically each cell < 10pixels on your average monitor) go figure another layout....